# Google API insufficient permissions

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-directory-api

I'm trying to add a gmail user to a group using google's api in python.
Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/admin-directory_v1-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret1.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Directory API Python Quickstart'
GROUP = 'customerservice@zego.com'


def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'admin-directory_v1-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

    groupinfo = {'email': 'david.bien@zego.com',
                  'role': 'MEMBER',
                  }
    service.members().insert(groupKey=GROUP, body=groupinfo).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Whenever I run this I get the following error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/customerservice
%40zego.com/members?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

So far I have done the following to troubleshoot this:

1. I tested the quickstart code from google and it worked.
2. I tried out oauth playground and I entered the same json data and it worked

I am not sure what exactly is the issue here. Scope is correct(worked in oauth playground), code seems to be correct(request worked in oauth playground). The only thing I can think of is request type? 
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your credentials don't have permission from google to do whatever you're trying to do. At least that's what the error message says. Have you checked with the google API documentation or asked on one of their forums?

Comment: I am the admin and I can create/delete/manage users and groups. I can do this from console panel.

Comment: it's what the error message says. Not believing the evidence of your own eyes isn't going to help you.

Comment: I understand that. I'm still baffled why this doesn't work with adding users to groups with my account while another script works fine(where I create users). For now I have asked google for help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "Insufficient Permission"

Means that the user who has authenticated the script in question does not have permission to do what you are trying to do.

Make sure that you have authenticated with a user that has access to add other users.

Comment: I'm the admin and I can freely add and remove users from the console.

Comment: Is the admin running your script?   I think you should try and reauthenticate it again make sure you didn't login with the wrong user.

Comment: I only have admin account. I tried to re-authenticate but still the same. The code looks fine, yes? I guess I will need to contact google directly.

Comment: it looks good even the  scope looks corect. 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group   The error means that you dont have permission.   So something is wrong with the user you are logging in with.   Have you tried inserting a different user maybe there is something wrong with that one

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.
I used some older credentials and as the code show they were stored inside

```
~/.credentials
```

Which did not work.
I just changed the directory to the folder where all my files are stored:

```
./.credentials
```

Ran this again and it worked. Thanks guys for your help.